# wxPython - wx.Button class

Tags: python, wxpython

Just started playing around with wxPython and came across the wx.Button class, can someone tell me what the '&' does in the sample labels, why it's there and why its in a different place for some, but not others, like below

```
wx.ID_CLOSE     '&Close'
wx.ID_COPY      '&Copy'
wx.ID_CUT       'Cu&t'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersand indicates what accelerator key the user can press in combination with <kbd>Alt</kbd> (or perhaps some other key like <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on Macs?) to click the button.

For example, if the label is `"&Close"`, then pressing <kbd>Alt-C</kbd> will click the button.

If instead you want a literal ampersand in the label, repeat the ampersand twice: `&&`.

I don't think you can profitably set two labels to have the same accelerator key, e.g. `"&Close"` and `"&Copy"`. Only the first label will react to <kbd>Alt-C</kbd>.